# Error The key "username" must be a string, "NULL" given

Tags: login, symfony3

Estoy usando Symfony 3.4 y estoy intentando crear un login para que me autentique usuarios. Este es el código:

security.yml

```
security:
    encoders:
        AppBundle\Entity\User:
            algorithm: bcrypt
        Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface: plaintext
    # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#b-configuring-how-users-are-loaded
    providers:
        our_db_provider:
            entity:
                class: AppBundle:User

        users_in_memory:
            memory:
                users:
                    admin:
                        password: admin
                        roles: 'ROLE_ADMIN'
        in_memory:
            memory: ~

    firewalls:
        # disables authentication for assets and the profiler, adapt it according to your needs
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false

        admin:
            pattern: ^/admin
            http_basic: ~
            provider: users_in_memory

        main:
            anonymous: ~
            provider: our_db_provider

            form_login:
                login_path: /login
                check_path: /login_check
                failure_path: homepage
                default_target_path: index_cliente
                username_parameter: username
                password_parameter: password

            logout:
                path: /logout
                target: /
```

LoginController.php

```php
namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authentication\AuthenticationUtils;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

class LoginController extends Controller{

    /**
     * @Route("/login", name="login")
     */
    public function loginAction(Request $request, AuthenticationUtils $authenticationUtils){

        // get the login error if there is one
        $error = $authenticationUtils->getLastAuthenticationError();

        // last username entered by the user
        $lastUsername = $authenticationUtils->getLastUsername();

        return $this->render('User/login.html.twig', [
            'last_username' => $lastUsername,
            'error'         => $error,
        ]);

    }

    /**
     * @Route("/login_check", name="login_check")
     */
    public function loginCheckAction()
    {
    }

}

?>
```

routing.yml

```
login:
  path:     /login
  defaults: { _controller: AppBundle:Login:login }

login_check:
    path: /login_check

logout:
    path: /logout
```

UserRepository.php

```php
namespace AppBundle\Repository;

use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Security\User\UserLoaderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\UsernameNotFoundException;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use AppBundle\Entity\User;

/**
 * UserRepository
 *
 * This class was generated by the Doctrine ORM. Add your own custom
 * repository methods below.
 */
class UserRepository extends EntityRepository implements UserLoaderInterface
{

    public function loadUserByUsername($usernameOrEmail){
        return $this->createQuery(
                'SELECT u
                FROM AppBundle\Entity\User u
                WHERE u.username = :query
                OR u.email = :query'
            )
            ->setParameter('query', $usernameOrEmail)
            ->getQuery()
            ->getOneOrNullResult();

    }
}
```

login.html.twig

```
<div id="form">
    <fieldset>
    <form action="{{ path('login_check') }}" method="POST">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <label for="username"> Usuario o Email: </label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" id="username" name="usermane" value="{{ last_username }}" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <label for="password"> Contraseña: </label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="password" id="password" name="password" />
                    <input type="hidden" name="_target_path" value="/user/cliente"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2" align="center">
                    <br>
                    <input type="submit" value="Iniciar Sesión" />
                    <input type="reset" value="Borrar" />
                </td>

            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
    </fieldset>
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

Al intentar hacer el login, despues de meter el username y el password y darle a enviar me sale el siguiente error:

*The key "username" must be a string, "NULL" given.*

En la Base de Datos esta bien metido el usuario, con el password codificado.

Entiendo que es como si al enviar el formulario en username no se enviara nada pero no lo entiendo porque si esta relleno cuando le doy a enviar...

¿Alguien que me pueda echar una mano por favor?
Gracias.

Comment: El problema está en el `form`. No encuentra el dato porque el `name` de tu input está escrito así: `name="usermane"` cámbialo por esto: **`name="username"`** y debería funcionar.

Comment: @A.Cedano Muchas gracias!!! Te prometo que lo he revisado infinidad de veces y lo leia bien aun estando mal escrito... que error mas tonto... Muchas gracias de nuevo!

Comment: A todos nos ha pasado lo mismo infinidad de veces. Errores tontos y no los vemos. Solución: > Una pausa... un café (o lo que te guste) ... volver a revisar el código... y encuentras el error. Saludos.